# res.redirect() is not working in promise in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

**File: router.js**

This file contain a post route to login page.

```js
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();
const users = require('./function');

// POST Login route
route.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    users.getUserInfo(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        .then(userDetails => {
            req.session.userId = userDetails.id;
            req.session.userName = userDetails.name;
            req.session.userEmail = userDetails.email;
            console.log(req.session);
            res.redirect('/dashboard');  // Not working
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.end(err);
        })
});

// Dashboard route
route.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user)
        res.render('dashboard', { title: "Dashboard", user: req.session.user });
    else
        res.redirect('/login');
});
```

All is working, but in file: **router.js**

```js
res.redirect('/dashboard');
```

line is **not working**.

When i print i get the correct data.

```js
console.log(req.session);
```

**File: function.js**

This file contains a function getUserInfo() which return User details from users.json file.

if users entered credential on login page matched with any details stored in users.json.

if users credential not match it return "Incorrect Email or Passoword";

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// Get user information
exports.getUserInfo = (email, password) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('./users.json', (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err);

            let userDetails = null;
            const users = JSON.parse(data);
            users.forEach(user => {
                if (email == user.email && password == user.password) {
                    userDetails = {
                        id: user._id,
                        name: user.name,
                        email: user.email
                    };
                    resolve(userDetails);
                }
            });
            reject("Incorrect Email or Passoword");
        });
    });
}
```

**File: users.json**

```json
[
    {
        "_id": 101,
        "name": "User",
        "email": "user123@gmail.com",
        "password": "user123"
    },
    {
        "_id": 102,
        "name": "Admin",
        "email": "admin111@gmail.com",
        "password": "admin111"
    }
]
```

Why res.redirect() is not working ?

Comment: "not working" - is there an error or is there no redirect at all?

Comment: res.redirect() not working means it's not redirecting to '/dashboard' just realoads login page.

Comment: Ok, can you show the response-headers for the POST /login request?

Comment: **Response Headers:** Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 64
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 29 Jul 2022 10:41:31 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Location: /dashboard
Vary: Accept
X-Powered-By: Express

Comment: This looks ok - is `dashboard` served statically or do you have a route like `app.get("/dashboard", (req,res) => ....)` ?

Comment: Yes, i have route for '/dashboard' i have now added to file **router.js** . but the problem is that when i login i am not creating user variable in session i am creating userId,userName and userEmail. That's why when i redirect to dashboard if condition check for req.session.user which is not set, then it direct back to '/login'.

Comment: How are you mounting your router onto your app?

Comment: Now, all working good. Thanks @eol for helping.